# How to extract individual digits from a list of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, cs50

Being new to python this has been giving me some trouble

Given a list of integers like

```
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8]
```

how might I extract the indiviual digits of each element to form a new list

```
 [2,1,2,8]
```

I've had the idea of iterating through each element and using the modulo operator but I cant seem to find the correct logic

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Does order of the elements in the list matter?

Like 20 should be decomposed as 0 then 2 or should 2 come first?

Comment: @SumedhPatkar No the order in this case will not matter. I simply need to extract each individual digit and then add them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way, I think, is to convert the values to string and extract separate characters and convert them back to integer.

For example:

```
lst = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8]

digits = []
for value in lst:
    if value != 0:
        digits.extend(map(int, str(value)))

print(digits)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 1, 2, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first convert all the numbers into lists of strings, convert each string to a integer, then flatten the result with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(int, str(x)) for x in lst if x != 0))
[2, 1, 2, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 0 is also a digit, Imagine the following case if a number is like 10, 20, 30, 40..... Then it should be like 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0... respectively.

> SO DO YOU NEED 0 IN YOUR NEW LIST?

If the answer to this question is "NO" Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701692/12752997) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701692/12752997) answers fails. Here's one solution.

```
myList = [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8]

newList = []
for i in myList:
    while i >= 10:
        newList.append(i%10)
        i = i//10
    newList.append(i)

newList = [ x for x in newList if x != 0 ]
```

This solution also satisfies your modulo logic.